# ASP.NET Project error. This site can't be reached

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an asp.net project that is deployed on a windows server 2012 R2. From time to time I get an error in chrome ***This site can't be reach. 'Website' took too long to respond.***

I have a good internet conection. I checked the EventView and the logs files from IIS but no error was logged there.

The error appears at random time and not very often.

If I use another browser the website would work but from Chrome I have to wait a while in order to work again even if I clear the cache.

The application is used by 10 persons.

Do you guys have any ideea/suggestions what could cause this issue?

Comment: This error occurs randomly only on chrome, there is no possibility to reproduce the problem. Have you tried reinstalling or resetting chrome. Have any other users encountered this error and are all using chrome browser? 
 May you can refer to this link: https://www.seoptimer.com/blog/website-taking-too-long-to-respond/#Chromes-default-profile-folder-issues.

Comment: @TengFeiXie I did not try to reinstail chrome or reseting it. I will try it. Also other users had encountered this error and they are all using chrome.